# Filtering user and showing his informations- django

Tags: django, database, templates

i need some help in following situation.

After a successful searching for a user, i want to show the users information. It's a m2m flied, but I'm getting all objects from this model.
I do not know, how to filter users information.

Got this template:

```
 {% for player in players %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ player.last_name }} <span class="text-muted">({{ player.first_name }})</span></td>
                    <td>{{ player.gender }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% for choice in search.league %}
                        <div class="">
                            {{ choice }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
```

This way it is showing all objects in League.
The field league is a M2M field from player.

I have this in my forms.Form

```
  league = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=League.objects.all())
```

I realize that I must also send the users-information from the view, but I do not know how.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: is league and players has a m2m relation?

Comment: i edited my question now. The field league is a m2m from player

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you want to use something like `{% for choice in player.league.all %}` in your template and use it in your for-loop. You can find more information about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name